# HTML5 Import and Angular controller binding

Tags: angularjs, html, controller

**Given**

I'm using HTML5 web components via the `<link rel="import..."` construct.  Am 
   able to breakup large HTML markup into smaller portions and import them at will into a container (web page) that puts all the smaller parts together.  Cool so far.

Now I want to use Angular data binding to be able to show dynamic content in those smaller pages.  In my main Index.html page I am able to declare the ng-app in the first Div tag no problem.  The angular.module is declared in that page as well.  I can get the binding to work if I put all controller logic into main page.

**Problem**

I'd like to do is split each controller script shown below to be contained in the imported page and not just in the main index.html where it's working now.

```
  <script>
        angular.module('ResultsApp', [])
            .controller('CardsController', ['$scope',
                function ($scope) {
                    $scope.results = {
                        'Passed': '12',
                        'Failed': '3',
                        'Warnings': '5',
                        'Summary': '20'
                    }
                }
            ])
        .controller('ResultsController', ['$scope',
            function ($scope) {
                $scope.results = [
                    { Name: "The Name of something to display", Passed: "True", Failed: "False", Comments: "These are the comments yes! Comments" },
                    { Name: "The Name of something to display", Passed: "True", Failed: "False", Comments: "These are the comments yes! Comments" },
                    { Name: "The Name of something to display", Passed: "True", Failed: "False", Comments: "These are the comments yes! Comments" },
                    { Name: "The Name of something to display", Passed: "True", Failed: "False", Comments: "These are the comments yes! Comments" },
                    { Name: "The Name of something to display", Passed: "True", Failed: "False", Comments: "These are the comments yes! Comments" },
                    { Name: "The Name of something to display", Passed: "True", Failed: "False", Comments: "These are the comments yes! Comments" },
                    { Name: "The Name of something to display", Passed: "True", Failed: "False", Comments: "These are the comments yes! Comments" },
                    { Name: "The Name of something to display", Passed: "True", Failed: "False", Comments: "These are the comments yes! Comments" }

                ];
            }]);
    </script>
```

I've tried putting the controller logic into each imported page but it doesn't seem to work.  I am only attempting to use one ng-app defined in main page...  Please advise.

Ok if I move the code to a partial page like this, where TestResultsApp is on the main page (Index) call this page "pageheading.html" :

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="HeaderController">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="page-header">
        {{header.Title}}
    </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li class="active">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard">Some Data Here</i> 
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    angular.module('HeaderModule', ['TestResultsApp'])
    .controller('HeaderController', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.header = { "Title": "Pretty Good, Test Case Results Right here!" }
        }])
</script>
```

**The New Error**
  The partial page, can't find angular... More on this tomorrow...

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading this right, you'll need to use `ng-controller` on each page that utilizes the controller, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I tried that once but will try again and post back results.

Comment: I posted new results in question... Please advise.

Comment: Seems like the web components aren't building it as one page before the js is loading.  Try adding `ng-app="ResultsApp"` as well as `ng-controller` to the partial page(s).

Comment: Thanks Chris; I'm going to ask question anew, with exact details of what I'm seeing.